# Интересная сигнатура функции C++

Tags: c++, signature

**Здравствуйте!**

Вот недавно (что, возможно, странно) я обнаружил, что в C++ можно задавать сигнатуры функций подобным образом:

```
BOOL PrintMsg(HANDLE hOut,...)
{

}
```

Троеточие после запятой - это что? Неограниченное число параметров? Если да, то какой переменной она задаются, т.е каким образом к ним получать доступ? Можете, пожалуйста, пояснить?

**Спасибо!**

Comment: называется var-args, эквивалент массива

Comment: @Asen Если вам стали интересны `va_arg's,` то можете почитать и про [`variadic templates.`](http://alenacpp.blogspot.com/2008/08/variadic-templates.html)

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, а почему вы пишете: "Если стали интересны" ? Их не рекомендовано использовать? Или может они уже слишком устарели?

Comment: Дело в том, что WinAPI функции по сути являются функциями языка Си. В С++, имеющем возможность перегрузки функций, функции с  вариабельными аргументами используются редко.

Comment: @mikillskegg, в принципе, это логично) Спасибо! Ведь с си не поддерживались классы, поэтому, ни о какой перегрузки и речи быть не могло...

Comment: @Asen, а при чем тут классы? Перегрузка функций может быть и без всякого ООП.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это свойство языка унаследовано из языка C. Таким же образом формируются функции с переменным количеством параметров вида printf и т.п. Делается это с помощью макросов [`va_arg, va_end, va_start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/kb57fad8(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Благодарю за разъяснения!

Comment: А va_end зачем нужен? Он же просто зануляет свой аргумент. Или на других платформах может что-то другое делать?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587128/what-exactly-is-va-end-for-is-it-always-necessary-to-call-it

> Each invocation of va_start() must be matched by a corresponding invocation of va_end() in the same function

Comment: Еще один важный для x86-64bit момент, это в некоторых случаях необходимо использовать **va_copy**, вместо va_start. 

Комментарий @Котик, отсылающий на SO, напомнил. 

Например: (не влезает)

    static void
    logmsg (char *fmt, va_list ap)
    {
      char pfx[100], *p;
    ...
      // Segmentation fault if don't use copy in second vfprintf() 
      va_list sap;
      va_copy(sap,ap);
    ...
      if (log) {
        fputs(pfx,log);
        vfprintf(log,fmt,ap);
    ...
      }
     if (...) {
        ...
        vfprintf (stderr,fmt,sap);
     }
     va_end(sap);
    }

Думаю, понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример использования.

```
int function_(int first , ...)
{
std::cout << "\nпервый=" << first;
int * arguments = &first; // получаем адрес первого аргумента

arguments++; // увеличиваем адрес указателя
std::cout << "\nвторой=" << *arguments;

arguments++;
std::cout << "\nтретий=" << *arguments;
return 1;
}

int main()
{
std::system("chcp 1251");
function_(5 , 7 , 10);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, конечно же...но что вы будете делать, если, скажем в функцию передать 10-100 параметров? Вы их все будете также "тупо" перебирать? Это абсурдно. Ведь так гораздо рациональнее:

    void function_(int i,...)
    {
 va_list list;
 va_start(list,i);
 int *c=&i;

 do
 {
 cout<<*c<<endl;
 }while((*(++c)));

 va_end(list);
    }

Comment: Это просто простой пример. Чтобы было понятно каким образом он функционирует.

Comment: @manking, так работать с переменным количеством параметров **нельзя!!!** Это абсолютно непереносимо. Да, в 32-бит x86 работает, а в 64-бит нет. Во многих архитектурах работать не будет.

Правильно использовать va_list. Т.е. Ваш пример д.б. написан так:

    int function_v (int first , ...)
    {
      va_list a;
      va_start(a,first);
      std::cout << "\nпервый=" << first;
      std::cout << "\nвторой=" << va_arg(a, int);
      std::cout << "\nтретий=" << va_arg(a, int);
      va_end(a);
      std::cout << '\n';
      return 1;
    }

Ваш пример в 64-бит ubuntu (места мало см. след.)

Comment: Ваш пример в 64-бит ubuntu (продолжение)

    первый=5
    второй=-1667615712
    третий=32731

а правильный вариант

    первый=5
    второй=7
    третий=10

Не вводите людей в заблуждение такими "ответами".